# How to compare a character from a string from a vector string?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<string> color;
color.push_back("RBBG");
color.push_back("RBBBBG");
if (color [1] [2] == "B"){
     cout<<"it is blue";
}
```

It gives the following error :

`error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
          if (colors [i] [m] == "R")`

**P.S** : The code provided is just a snippet that was edited a bit to get rid of irrelevant things for the question :D

How can I fulfill my purpose?

Answer (score 3):

`color` is a vector of `std::string`.

`color[1]` is an `std::string`.

`color[1][1]` is a character, of type `char`.

`"R"` is a string literal, of type `const char *`.

Note the different count of stars in the two types (0 vs 1). Characters are not strings, you cannot compare one with the other.

You may want to use a *character literal* instead of a string literal, e.g. `'R'` (note single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

`color` is a vector of strings, and at each index of a string is a character, not a string.
Change the `if` condition to `if (color [1] [2] == 'B')`